# Jquery prevAll() in Angular way

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have 4 empty star icons. And every time it goes forward the previous star will be shaded. Just like `prevAll()` in `Jquery` sample in this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_traversing_prevall). But I want it to be done in Angular way.

So far this is my work:

```
<ul>
    <li test-case condition="someConditions" class="star glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></li>
    <li test-case condition="someConditions" class="star glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></li>
    <li test-case condition="someConditions" class="star glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></li>
    <li test-case condition="someConditions" class="star glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></li>
</ul>
```

My directive:

```
.directive('testCase', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'condition': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('condition', function(condition){
                if(condition){
                    element.prevAll().addClass('glyphicon-star'); // this line won't work
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

I didn't include all the conditions in the `li`. So don't mind how can I tell where the progress of star is.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Just a hint: use angular 'ng-class'

Comment: See my example, it has an another perspective

Answer (score 2):

`.prevAll()` method is not provided by jqLite. For this you need to use jQuery or better to use `ng-class` directive.

[More about angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

---

With `ng-class` directive:

```
<li test-case ng-class="{glyphicon-star:someConditions}"></li>
```

[Plnkr in action.](http://plnkr.co/edit/vRpLBr7hdCRMNJf7GbPT?p=preview)

Comment: Can't find a way using `ng-class`. Let say the `second star` hold the `id`. Then the `first star` must be shaded, `second, third and fourth star` must be empty.

Answer (score 1):

A Vanilla JavaScript alternative to prevAll if you do not want load full jQuery library (because jqLite not provided prevAll) is this code:

```
var prevAll = true;
prevAll = [].filter.call(<htmlElement>.parentNode.children, function (htmlElement) {
    return (htmlElement === <htmlElement>) ? prevAll = false : prevAll;
});
```

And prevAll will contain all previous HTMLElement from your `<htmlElement>` in an array.

So in your case, code below may do the job:

```
.directive('testCase', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'condition': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('condition', function(condition){
                var element = element[0],
                    prevAll = true;
                if(condition){
                    prevAll = [].filter.call(element.parentNode.children, function (htmlElement) {
                        return (htmlElement === element) ? prevAll = false : prevAll;
                    });
                    $(prevAll).addClass("glyphicon-star");
                    // or alternativly
                    /*
                     * [].forEach.call(prevAll, function (item) {
                     *     item.classList.add("glyphicon-star");
                     * });
                     */
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

[More Vanilla alternavive for jqLite and jQuery here](https://github.com/Haeresis/vanilla-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can think **differently** and try **without jQuery**:

What do you think about make a directive who receive the quantity of stars and will render every star for you?

```js
var app = angular.module('example', []);

app.controller('exampleController', function($scope) {
  $scope.fool = {
    rating: 5
  }
});

app.directive('testCaseCollection', function () {
    var getStars = function(rating) {
      var stars = [];
      for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        stars.push({
          active: (i <= rating)
        });
      }
      return stars;
    };
  
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'rating': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('rating', function(rating) {
                scope.stars = getStars(rating);
            })
        },
        template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="star.active ? \'cls-1\' : \'cls-2\'">{{star.active}}</li></ul>'
    }
});
```

```css
.cls-1 {
  color: red;
}

.cls-2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="example">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="exampleController">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="5" ng-model="fool.rating" />
    <p>Your selected rating is: {{fool.rating}}</p>
    <div test-case-collection data-rating="fool.rating"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```